# GreenDao list entity with a list of entities

Tags: android, entity, greendao

I am making an Android application using GreenDao, and I have these two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Quiz {

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    private Date date;

    private String type;

    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "quizId")
    private List<Answer> answers;
}

@Entity
public class Answer {

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    private int answer;

    private float value;

    private int questionNumber;

    private String type;

    private Long quizId;
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the list of Quiz using the following code:

```
DaoSession daoSession = AndroidAdapter.getDaoSession();
QuizDao quizDao = daoSession.getQuizDao();
List<Quiz> quizs = quizDao.loadAll();
```

But the list of answers always comes empty, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure to have entered some quiz entities in your db?

Comment: Yes, with this code it lists all the saved Quiz, but the list of answers is always null.

Comment: Can you put some code of your AndroidAdapter class? ...Maybe you have some issue getting dao session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My AndroidAdapter class:

```
public class AndroidAdapter {

    public static Context getContext() {
        return AppApplication.getContext();
    }

    public static DaoSession getDaoSession() {
        return AppApplication.getDaoSession();
    }
}
```

And AppApplication class

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    context = this;

    DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this,ENCRYPTED ? "exam-db-encrypted" : "exam-db");
    Database db = ENCRYPTED ? helper.getEncryptedWritableDb("exam-secret") : helper.getWritableDb();
    daoSession = new DaoMaster(db).newSession();

    this.addAllEvents();
}

public static DaoSession getDaoSession() {
    return daoSession;
}
```

Comment: Try to get dao session directly from AppApplication class (it should extend Application class right?)
`DaoSession daoSession = ((AppApplication)getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession();`
Then try to get Quiz list again

Comment: I've changed, but keep bringing the Quiz without the list of answers.

Comment: @GiacomoLai this project I'm working on is a personal application. After the last time we talked, I dropped it and did not work on it anymore. Today I returned, but before, I restarted my machine and cleaned the project ... And it worked normally ¬ ¬ sorry to have bothered you and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I've not entered some Answer entities in my db.

Once I've added a code to add those entities to the db and I've requested the list with a generated getter for the `List<Answer> answers` - it all worked as it should